# Given a pd.Interval column in a dataframe, filter on value falling within Interval range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to assign each row in a dataframe an interval, such that the all rows won't overlap and will cover the whole possible range. Accordingly, I can filter rows based on values that falls within a given interval.

I've used `pd.Interval`, but when I've tried 'normal' filtering it didn't work:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"rating":["bad","average","good"],
                   "stars":[pd.Interval(left=0,right=2,closed="left"),
                            pd.Interval(left=2,right=4,closed="left"),
                            pd.Interval(left=4,right=5,closed="both")]})
stars_val=2.5
filtered_df = df[stars_val in df.stars]
```

It gave the following error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: False
```

A working code should give the result:

```py
    rating   stars
1  average  [2, 4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of your intervals have the same `closed`, then your column will be backed by an [`IntervalArray`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.arrays.IntervalArray.html) and you can use the [`IntervalArray.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.arrays.IntervalArray.contains.html) method for a vectorized implementation:

```
In [2]: np.random.seed(123)

In [3]: start = np.random.randint(100, size=1000)

In [4]: ia = pd.arrays.IntervalArray.from_arrays(start, start + 5)

In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('abcde') * 200, 'B': ia})

In [6]: df.head()
Out[6]: 
   A          B
0  a   (66, 71]
1  b   (92, 97]
2  c  (98, 103]
3  d   (17, 22]
4  e   (83, 88]

In [7]: df[df['B'].array.contains(70)]
Out[7]: 
     A         B
0    a  (66, 71]
20   a  (68, 73]
23   d  (67, 72]
27   c  (66, 71]
45   a  (69, 74]
87   c  (67, 72]
111  b  (65, 70]
128  d  (68, 73]
133  d  (65, 70]
135  a  (67, 72]
155  a  (65, 70]
177  c  (69, 74]
193  d  (67, 72]
217  c  (69, 74]
221  b  (66, 71]
223  d  (69, 74]
227  c  (66, 71]
243  d  (66, 71]
250  a  (67, 72]
251  b  (65, 70]
263  d  (68, 73]
407  c  (65, 70]
419  e  (69, 74]
425  a  (65, 70]
446  b  (69, 74]
449  e  (69, 74]
451  b  (66, 71]
523  d  (66, 71]
552  c  (68, 73]
589  e  (66, 71]
609  e  (69, 74]
613  d  (68, 73]
627  c  (69, 74]
637  c  (68, 73]
650  a  (67, 72]
674  e  (69, 74]
711  b  (69, 74]
769  e  (67, 72]
777  c  (69, 74]
800  a  (66, 71]
803  d  (68, 73]
818  d  (69, 74]
822  c  (67, 72]
883  d  (66, 71]
889  e  (68, 73]
944  e  (67, 72]
953  d  (69, 74]
966  b  (65, 70]
```

Mixed `closed` intervals results in an `object` array, so you'll need to use a less efficient implementation like what @ALollz suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it:

```
filtered=[]
for i in df.index:   
    filtered.append(stars_val in df.stars[i])
filtered_df=df[filtered]
```

Output:

```
    rating  stars
1   average [2, 4)
```

---

**Explanation:**

```
stars_val in df.stars
```

Output:

```
False
```

keep in mind that you need a list of booleans to filter df,
after executing my code you will get:

```
filtered
```

Output:

```
[False, True, False]
```

because of this `df[filtered]` works, because the length of the list matches the length of the column of your dataframe

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I preferred @ALollz [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57719432/11996983), as it's a one-liner that can be used more easier with other operators for extra filtering.

Answer (score 1):

`df.stars` is a Series. You want to check if `stars_val` is in each Interval of the Series

```
filtered_df = df[[stars_val in x for x in df.stars]]

    rating   stars
1  average  [2, 4)
```